# Multiple Parameters for jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I was just looking at the jQueryUI button plug-in and noticed this

```
$("button, input:submit, a", ".demo").button();
```

I never seen something like this. Is this like multiple selects in one jQuery selector?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The second argument (`".demo"` in your example) is the *context*, basically your selector is restricted to match only descendants of a determined *context*:

```
$(expr, context)
```

Is just equivalent to use the [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$(context).find(expr)
```

Give a look to the documentation of the [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1):

> Selector Context
>
> By default, selectors perform their
>   searches within the DOM starting at
>   the document root. However, an
>   alternate context can be given for the
>   search by using the optional second
>   parameter to the `$()` function. For
>   example, if within a callback function
>   we wish to do a search for an element,
>   we can restrict that search:

```
$('div.foo').click(function() {
  $('span', this).addClass('bar');
  // it will find span elements that are
  // descendants of the clicked element (this)
});
```

Also notice that the selector you post `"button, input:submit, a"`, is called [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), and there you can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result, just by separating them by a comma.

Comment: Cool never knew that.  When I wanted to limit say like a class sector so it would not search the entire page I just did something like $('#id .class')

Comment: That really is backwards from what you would have thought looking at the source.  I would expect the first arg to be the super class followed by subclasses which narrow it down. Ah well.

Comment: Is it faster for the browser if I define a context?

Answer (score -2):

to actually supply multiple different arguments to a jQuery selector though, just give the selector an array with all your arugments, like

```js
$([sel1, sel2, sel3, obj1, obj2, obj3]).on("click", function() {
    alert("clicked!");
});
```