# Jquery picture slideshow only affect one DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, slideshow

i have the simple slideshow code like this :

```
function anim() {
    $(".images img").first().appendTo('.images').fadeOut(500);
    $(".images img").first().fadeIn(500);    
    setTimeout(anim, 5000);
}
```

And this my html code

```
<div class="subbox-1">
        <div class="caption">
               <div class="caption-text">
                   <h3>COAL MINING</h3>
                      <p>
                           Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.
                      </p>
               </div>
         </div>
         <div class="images">
                <img src="images/thumb1.jpg" />
                <img src="images/thumb1-1.jpg" />
                <img src="images/thumb1-2.jpg" />
                <img src="images/thumb1-3.jpg" />
         </div>
</div>
```

And i have many `.subbox-1` with different image source. But my Jquery code just works in one `.subbox-1` images, if i have two `.subbox-1` the second `.subbox-1`'s images wont to change.

Please help me, Thanks before :)

Comment: Show your code here to understand what is happening there..

Comment: @NeerajSingh I'm sorry, this is the result [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/fanjavaid/DUtSG/) ,
and for Spokey Nothing error, in my console log. Just the second, third, etc slidehow not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) so that the search would be carried out only to descendants of the context. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2672034/155813) for more discussions on this topic.

Basically your `anim` function will take 1 argument:

```
function anim(selector) {
    ...
}
```

and you would pass the context (usually `this`) to your `anim` function as such:

```
$(".subbox-1").each(function() {anim(this)});
```

EDIT:

- [OP's snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/mihirgokani007/G9qu7/)
- [Modified](http://jsfiddle.net/mihirgokani007/G9qu7/1/)