# wrapper issue with the DOM structure using jquery

Tags: jquery, dhtml

I have an issue where I have the following jQuery and mark up working although if I move the location of `textarea` the `.click()` event doesn't fire.  I haven't seen this `$('element', something)` before.  What does the `$wrapper` syntax mean please?  Thanks,

```
 this.each(function () {
     var $field = $(this);
     var $wrapper = $field.parent();


      $('.myClass', $wrapper)
          .click(function () { 
              // do stuff
          });

<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <img src="x" class="myClass" />
</div>
```

Comment: An answer to one of your questions is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672034/multiple-parameters-for-jquery-selector

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please clarify what you exactly need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that `$(this)` refers to the `textarea`, which isn't clear from your question.

The second parameter in `$('.myClass', $wrapper)` refers to the context of the first parameter. That is, the first parameter is a descendant of the second parameter.

If `$field` is your text area, the context of `.myClass` is the parent of the `textarea` (as that is how you've defined `$wrapper`).

If you move the `textarea` out of the DIV that also contains `.myClass`, your context changes. Since `.myClass` is no longer in that context, the event handler is not bound to it.

If you want the click event bound to `.myClass` irrespective of context, use:

```
$('.myClass').click(function () { 
     // do stuff
});
```