# Limiting the jQuery search scope correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've stumbled up this code  and I'm wondering if its just limiting the scope or selecting both of the elements at the same time.

```
container = jQuery("#test", parent.document);

jQuery("param[name=scale]", another.object)
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Edit: the full example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery = parent.jQuery;
container = jQuery("#test", parent.document);

another = {
    targetw: container.width()
};

function onEnd(){
  container.slideUp();
}

function onStart(){
  another.object = jQuery("object", document);

  another.w =  another.object.attr("width");
  another.h =  another.object.attr("height");
  another.targeth = Math.floor(another.targetw * another.h  / another.w);

  jQuery("div>iframe",container).width(another.targetw);
  jQuery("div>iframe",container).height(another.targeth);

  another.object.css("width", another.targetw+"px");
  another.object.css("height", another.targeth+"px");

  another.object.attr("width", another.targetw);
  another.object.attr("height", another.targeth);

  jQuery("param[name=scale]",another.object).attr("value","exactfit");

  another.object.parent().attr('style', function(i,s) { return s + 'background:none; width: '+another.targetw+'px !important; height: '+another.targeth+'px !important;' });

}
document.write('*snipped code*');
</script>
```

`

Comment: That's the context parameter, equivalent to: `$(parent.document).find('#test')`. BUT your example is not really accurate as IDs must be unique on document context, so better is just to use `$('#test')`     https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

Comment: The second parameter limits the scope of the selector context. This allows  jquery to find the object quicker instead of searching the entire dom. To search for multiple selectors its done like this $(".intro,.demo") and you can then use the second parameter to limit the scope. Duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672034/multiple-parameters-for-jquery-selector

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's on the first page of the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That appears to be the context argument from the jQuery selector `jQuery(selector[,context])`.

From http://api.jquery.com/jquery/

**Selector Context**

By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the `$()` function. For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be restricted like so:

```
$( "div.foo" ).click(function() {
  $( "span", this ).addClass( "bar" );
});
```

When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of `this`, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional class.

Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so  `$( "span", this )` is equivalent to  `$( this ).find( "span" )`.

Answer (score 3):

It is a child - parent selector. The search starts within the parent instead of the whole DOM.

```
$('childNode', parent)
```

It is same as

```
$(parent).find('childNode')
```

Considering `container = jQuery("#test", parent.document);`

As `#test` is an ID based selector just `jQuery('#test')` wont make any difference as IDs are unique across the DOM elements.