# Jquery element class testing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand some codes that i have inherited. I'm not a jquery professional although i somewhat can work with it. Here is the peice of code that is confusing me

```
 wrapper = $('#' + field + "_" + matches[1] + "_wrapper");
    if (wrapper.length > 0 && wrapper.is(':visible')
    && $('.ds-interpreted-field-removed', wrapper).length === 0) 
    {return wrapper;}
```

What is really confusing me is

```
$('.ds-interpreted-field-removed', wrapper).length === 0)
```

I don't understand what that code does.

What i know is that this code is part of a function that is testing if some item is present in a list of field when someone try to undo the deletion of an item.

For instance you have 1 2 3  where 3 is marked as delete and then when clicking undo, check must be made that 3 has not been added in the list again or let say a multiple of 3. What i understand is that the code tries to check everything but itself, where itself is the item marked as delete, which is represented by
**'.ds-interpreted-field-removed'**

Here is how look the html list:

[image: Code image here]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is tests whether there are `0` `.ds-interpreted-field-removed` elements inside `wrapper`.

Comment: Does that help: [Multiple Parameters for jQuery selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2672034/218196). I assume you know that `.length` gets the number of elements, `===` is equality comparison, and `0` represents the number zero.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks but what kind of selection is that i mean where can i find some documentation about that ?

Comment: In the official jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1, https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context . Does the other Stack Overflow question / answer help?

Comment: All good understood thank you