# Understanding jQuery's .remove() method in an AJAX scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In Chapter 10 of of jQuery In Action 3rd Edition, there's the following code sample:

```
$('#boot-chooser-control')
    .load('actions/fetch-boot-style-options.php')
    .change(function(event) {
       $('#product-detail-pane').load(
           'actions/fetch-product-details.php',
            {
              model: $(event.target).val()
            },
            function() {
               $('[value=""]', event.target).remove();
            }
          );
       });
```

The HTML for the document is (see below)

```
 <select id="boot-chooser-control" name="model"><option value="">choose a style</option>
     <option value="7177382">Caterpillar Tradesman Work Boot</option>
     <option value="7269643">Caterpillar Logger Boot</option>
     <option value="7141832">Chippewa 17" Engineer Boot</option>
  </select>
```

How is it that the following code

```
model: $(event.target).val()
```

in line 7 of the JS snippit is referring to the value of just one HTML element. But that very same selector in line 10 (seen below)

```
$('[value=""]', event.target).remove();
```

is somehow referencing ALL the option elements within the specified context? Isn't it weird that event.target in line 7 is selecting just one element, whereas on line 11 it's referring to each option element?

What am I missing... to me it seems like event.target is targeting two different things. On line 7 it targets JUST the element that has been selected. But on line 11 it is referencing ALL the elements in the specified context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line selects all elements which are in the context `event.target` and have no value.

This question describes the method: [Multiple Parameters for jQuery selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672034/multiple-parameters-for-jquery-selector)

So it does not remove any value but rather removes a whole dom object (f.e. a "div") which is, I guess, somwhere else added (if that's not all the code).

Comment: thanks for explaining this in a way I finally understood. I guess I just needed to hear it in different words.

Comment: Do you mind looking at my revised question. And, if it makes any sense, please comment

Comment: The `<select>` element is your `event.target` and the line `$(event.target).val()` returns the value of the currently selected option (that's how it works, see here https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/ ). The line `$('[value=""]', event.target).remove();` just goes through all options with no value and deletes them.

Answer (score 0):

It removes all elements with an empty value attribute under the `event.target` node from the DOM.

So for example if you have the following DOM:

```
<div id="target">
    <input value="">
    <input value="Hello">
    <input value="">
</div>
```

Then run the following jQuery:

```
var target = document.getElementById('target');
$('[value=""]', target).remove();
```

The resulting DOM will now be this:

```
<div id="target">
    <input value="Hello">
</div>
```

Comment: Your message helped me understand better what's happening. But I've updated my question... can you please take a look and comment