# only change classes inside a hovered element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

So I'm creating a page about user-submitted recipes. Some users have submitted a short quote about the recipe, others have not. I wanted to have the quote, if it exists, to display when the user hovers over the image of the recipe.

Right now, I'm using this:

```
$(".recipe").hover(function(){
            $(".slider-submit").hide();
            $(".slider-description").show();
        },
        function(){
            $(".slider-submit").show();
            $(".slider-description").hide();
        });
```

The first problem is that it changes for all the recipes, not just the one that is hovered on. The second problem is, I'm unsure how to check if the 'slider description' exists for that recipe or not.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebbBliss/bkyn40f8/2/) of what I'm working on. I'm still learning JQuery so give me any tips, please!

Comment: you can do this with just CSS, too. https://jsfiddle.net/bkyn40f8/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution with checking for non existent descriptions as well as using a more efficient hover function:

```
$(".recipe").hover(function(){
   if ($(".slider-description",this)[0]){
      $(".slider-submit",this).toggle();
   }
   $(".slider-description",this).toggle();
});
```

It uses the lesser known [`$(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) notation to only select the text elements within the hovered `.recipe` element.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poikl/bkyn40f8/10/)

Comment: Sorry for hijacking your answer, but I was thinking the same and didn't want to write another (reduntant) answer when I instead can improve and upvote an existing one.

Comment: Its because of people like you @Christoph that this community is growing and helping so many people. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for helping! This was the only answer to help with both parts of my  question. 
However, can you explain to me
'$(".slider-description",this)[0]'?

I'm a bit confused as to what this does/mean?

Comment: `if ($(".slider-description",this)[0])` checks if description is present, and if it is, then `$(".slider-submit",this).toggle()` toggles its state from `show` to `hide` or `hide` to `show`

Comment: @ebbBliss When you pass a second parameter into the jQuery selector, that becomes the "context" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672034/multiple-parameters-for-jquery-selector.  That is a good way to limit the scope.  If the first index of that result exists, then that means the selection found at least one item.  You can also use `$("selectiong").length` to find out how many elements were selected

Answer (score 5):

Change your JS like this:

```
$(".recipe").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".slider-submit").hide();
    $(this).find(".slider-description").show();
},
function(){
    $(this).find(".slider-submit").show();
    $(this).find(".slider-description").hide();
});
```

This way you will only target the sliders that belong to the element that is being hovered over, instead of target them all.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use `this` that gets passed in with the hover event to find the elements inside.

```js
$(".recipe").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".slider-submit").hide();
    $(this).find(".slider-description").show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find(".slider-submit").show();
    $(this).find(".slider-description").hide();
  });
```

```css
.recipe {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center
}

.slider-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0% 3% 3% 3%;
  color: white;
  white-space: normal;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.slider-text:not(.asparagus-slider) {
  padding: 6% 3% 3% 3%;
}

.slider-text>h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#asparagus {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0% 3% 3% 3%;
}

.slider-info {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.slider-description {
  display: none;
}

#chili-img,
#asparagus-img,
#macCheese-img,
#noBakePie-img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 recipe">
      <div class="slider-text">
        <h3>Bear Creek Chili</h3>
        <p class="slider-submit">
          Submitted by: Dottie User
        </p>
      </div>
      <img id="chili-img" src="http://mystateoffitness.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/big-game-chili.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 recipe">
      <div class="slider-text asparagus-slider">
        <h3 id="asparagus">Beer Battered Asparagus with Lemon Herb Dipping Sauce</h3>
        <p class="slider-submit">
          Submitted by: Chris User
        </p>
        <p class="slider-description">
          <em>"This is the only way that I can enjoy asparagus"</em>
        </p>
      </div>
      <img id="asparagus-img" src="http://food.fnr.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2007/9/10/0/IP0211_Beer_Battered_Asparagus.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.616.462.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 recipe">
      <div class="slider-text">
        <h3>Mac n' Cheese</h3>
        <p class="slider-submit">
          Submitted by: Annette User
        </p>
      </div>
      <img id="macCheese-img" src="https://images-gmi-pmc.edge-generalmills.com/c41ffe09-8520-4d29-9b4d-c1d63da3fae6.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 recipe">
      <div class="slider-text">
        <h3>No Bake Peanut Butter Pie</h3>
        <p class="slider-submit">
          Submitted by: Shari User
        </p>
        <p class="slider-description">
          <em>"This recipe makes enough for two pies - one for your guests and one just for you!"</em>
        </p>
      </div>
      <img id="noBakePie-img" src="http://cdn2.tmbi.com/TOH/Images/Photos/37/300x300/exps17834_CCT1227369D54B.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To expound on Lixus, the issue that you're facing is that in jQuery, when you do a selection, you are selecting EVERYTHING in the DOM.  What you wanted to do is limit your selection scope.

For example, look at the following JS:

```
 $(".slider-submit").hide();  // Global selection
 $(this).find(".slider-submit").hide();  // Limit search to only descendants of "this"
```

In jQuery, generally when you enter into a function passed into a jQuery object (like the event handler in the "hover" function) the `this` context will be the DOM element and not the jQuery object, so wrapping `this` with jQuery will give you the jQuery object like normal.

I updated your JSFiddle with this code. https://jsfiddle.net/bkyn40f8/5/