# How does the underline in this menu work?

Tags: html, css

I am learning html/css at the moment and was playing around with this piece of code [here](https://codepen.io/rm/pen/ldhon).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Uno</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#">Dos</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a href="#">Tres</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#">Quatro</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried editing it to stop the underline from returning back to its original location (at margin-left: 0%;), but have found that no matter what I do, the underline always returns back to its original position.
So far I have tried doing the following:

```
hr {  margin-left: 25%; ...)
```

to forcefully attempt to move the underline over to the second tab.
And also the following:

```
.two:active ~ hr { margin-left: 25%; ...}
```

on an actual html file I created and attempted to move the underline this way by clicking the link.
Finally, I also tried creating 2 identical html files but with the following difference between the two:

```
<li class="one" id="active"><a href="#">Uno</a></li>
```

and

```
<li class="two" id="active"><a href="#">Dos</a></li>
```

and attempted to try manipulate the underline when the page changes but this also failed.

I've also tried looking at this code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/netzamhafen/uba4tvjL/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=uba4tvjL) but some stuff here such as 'nth-child', I still have not learnt so it hasn't helped me much, other than giving me the idea to try out the 3rd attempt I wrote above.
I would love to find out what exactly is causing the underline to return back to its position everytime and if there's an easy way to fix this particular code.

Comment: Side note, it is invalid html - <hr> as a direct child of <ul>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it as another rule for the hover styles with an additional `active` class and without the `:hover` (e.g. `.active.two ~ hr`).  The have correct specificity (and not break the hover effect) you need to give some additional weight to the hover selector.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

li.one:hover ~ hr, .active.one ~ hr {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
li.two:hover ~ hr, .active.two ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

li.three:hover ~ hr, .active.three ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

li.four:hover ~ hr, .active.four ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Uno</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#">Dos</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three active"><a href="#">Tres</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#">Quatro</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's an HTML validation compliant version (Noticed this after [Pangloss' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591305/how-does-the-underline-in-this-menu-work/43591432#comment-74232357)):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

li.one:hover ~ li hr, .active.one ~ li hr {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

li.two:hover ~ li hr, .active.two ~ li hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

li.three:hover ~ li hr, .active.three ~ li hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

li.four:hover ~ li hr, .active.four ~ li hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

li hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Uno</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#">Dos</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three active"><a href="#">Tres</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#">Quatro</a></li>
    <li><hr></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have one additional question I would like to ask. What names (if any) do the comments in the ul have and what purpose do they fulfill? I have of course tried the code out without these comments but without them, the 4 tabs do not fit into the space and enter a new line.

Comment: @Yuxie Without the comments you have white space nodes between the `li` elements, which take up additional space and make your li wrap onto the new line.

Comment: I don't think you should bother with your first answer at all since it is invalid HTML.

Comment: I'm assuming the invalid part is that a non `<li>` element (hr) is inside an `<ul>`? Also, one other thing i've noticed is that using `<li><hr></li>` causes the underline to not move at all. Is there a different approach to this?

Comment: @Yuxie the underline not moving was caused by wrong specificity of the selectors. I fixed it and it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is part of the concept that  *on this page*  the underline always returns to the first menu item, since you ARE on that page - the animation is just a replacement for the usual regular hover styles for menu links.

Once you are on the second page you would change the `margin-left` settings accordingly (like in my snippet below) so that the underline marks the current (= second) page and moves to the other menu items when hovered. This is done by setting the `margin-left` of `hr` to the desired position (0, 25%, 50% or 75%). And the same principle would apply to the other pages.

EDIT: The `hover` styles for the other positions DO NOT have to be adjusted. The only thing that has to be added on the other pages is the different margin setting for `hr`, which can be done in the `<head>` tag of each page, inside a `<style>` tag:

```
<style type="text:css">
  .container hr {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
</style>
```

Here's a complete example for the second page:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.one:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.four:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Uno</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#">Dos</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a href="#">Tres</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#">Quatro</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so clearly I'm still very inexperienced with html/css so forgive me but is it good or bad practice to have multiple css files? Or is it preferred that whenever possible, that the file is just one massive one?

Comment: You don't have to have different CSS files - see my edited answer above. It's just that one setting for `hr` which has to be different in every file. You could insert that in the head of each page, or even use an inline style tag in the HTML code like `<hr style="margin-left: 25%" />`.

Comment: P.S.: With some javascript you could even automate that setting depending on which page you are (i.e. getting the last part of the URL, comparing it with the `href` attribute in the link set the margin-left accordingly),  but - especially for a beginner - that's much more complicated than just using the CSS I desrcibed.

Comment: I took the liberty to improve the code a bit. It uses a valid `li` element and all it needs is the `.active` class on the currently active menu point. @Yuxie have a look at it now.

Comment: @Christoph If you want to write your own answer, feel free to do so, but please don't overwrite mine, okay? (I set it back)

Comment: Why should i write a duplicate answer, when there is a valid answer that can be improved? Since you rolled back to your previous (bad) version, I will revoke my +1. After all, that is the whole point of the SO community - to improve each others answers - no need for pointless pride here. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501891/only-change-classes-inside-a-hovered-element/43502170#comment74060807_43502170.

Comment: @Christoph There's a difference between fixing typos and the like and coming up with a different solution. There's no problem if you post another answer that is an improvement of mine. But if it would be like as write, there would always only be ONE answer to every question - edited by everyone who answers. BTW, this has nothing to do with pride - well, maybe in your case, or why did you downvote an answer that you called "a valid answer" above?

Comment: There is a difference between an "valid" and a "good" answer. You  missed the point that `hr` is not a valid child element, which definitely should be addressed and that's why I dislike this answer.

Comment: @Christoph and that's why you gave it an upvote before and a downvote after I rejected your overwriting of my answer? (After all, it works, and that invalid HTML was not a cause for any problems concerning the question). It would be enough to *not* vote, and not play the insulted one...