# how to run all functions in one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want help in solving this problem
I want to run all functions in one click how can I do this

Is the code of jquery

```
 /*global $*/
    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        $(".click1 button").on("click", function click1() {
            $(this).parent(".click1").css("background-color", "#f00");
        });

        $(".click2 button").on("click", function click2() {
            $(this).parent(".click2").css("background-color", "#ff0");
        });

        $(".click3 button").on("click", function click3() {
            $(this).parent(".click3").css("background-color", "#f0f");
        });

        $("clickAll").on("click", function () {

            click1();
            click2();
            click3();
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can add clickAll selector next to the others one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672034/multiple-parameters-for-jquery-selector

Comment: Do you want a single button that fires all the other buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function.

```
 /*global $*/
    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        $(".click1 button").on("click", function click1() {
            $(this).parent(".click1").css("background-color", "#f00");
        });

        $(".click2 button").on("click", function click2() {
            $(this).parent(".click2").css("background-color", "#ff0");
        });

        $(".click3 button").on("click", function click3() {
            $(this).parent(".click3").css("background-color", "#f0f");
        });

        $("clickAll").on("click", function () {                
            $(".click1 button").trigger("click");
            $(".click2 button").trigger("click");
            $(".click3 button").trigger("click");
        });
    });
```

Comment: This could cause unwanted side effects with bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.triggerHandler`](https://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) to fire the event without bubbling:

```js
/*global $*/
$(function() {
  'use strict';
  var clickMe = function(event, parent, bgColor) {
    $(event.target).parent(parent).css("background-color", bgColor);
  };

  var $click1Button = $(".click1 button");
  $click1Button.on("click", function(event) {
    clickMe(event, ".click1", "#f00");
  });

  var $click2Button = $(".click2 button");
  $click2Button.on("click", function(event) {
    clickMe(event, ".click2", "#ff0");
  });

  var $click3Button = $(".click3 button");
  $click3Button.on("click", function(event) {
    clickMe(event, ".click3", "#f0f");
  });

  $(".clickAll").on("click", function() {
    $click1Button.triggerHandler("click");
    $click2Button.triggerHandler("click");
    $click3Button.triggerHandler("click");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click1"><button>click1</button></div>
<div class="click2"><button>click2</button></div>
<div class="click3"><button>click3</button></div>

<div class="clickAll"><button>clickAll</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code executed in each handler is slightly the same, you can use event delegation to reduce the code required and moving what's related to the view in your html markup.

```js
  $(function(){
      $("#common_ancestor").on('click', function (evt){
          let $button = $(evt.target)
            // Depending on your markup, you way use closest() or parents() instead of parent() here.
            , $parent = $button.parent()
            , clickSelector = '[class*="click"]'
            ;
          // Test which button was triggered based on its parent
          if ($parent.is('.clickAll')) {
             $(this).find(clickSelector).each(function() {
                 this.style.backgroundColor = $(this).data('color');
             })
          } else if ($parent.is(clickSelector)) {
             $parent[0].style.backgroundColor = $parent.data('color');
          }
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="common_ancestor">
  <div class="click1" data-color="#f00"><button>click1</button></div>
  <div class="click2" data-color="#ff0"><button>click2</button></div>
  <div class="click3" data-color="#f0f"><button>click3</button></div>
   <div class="clickAll"><button>clickAll</button></div>
</div>
```

Pros on using event delegation:

- You don't need to register listener again when injecting additionnal `<div class="clickn" data-color="#ff0"><button>clickn</button></div>` elements in "#common_ancestor" div.
- Only one function object is created in memory.

Cons:
 - If you have non trivial behavior or code that differs slightly between targes, your uniq handler might quickly become bloated, which might affect code readability a lot in the long term.