# Trying to find this on click and then toggle class?

Tags: javascript, html, this

I'm trying to toggle the class of this on click, I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? I have included some HTML now so that it is more easily understood what is going on.

```
    $('.play-with-friends').on('click', function(){
        $('.flipper', this).toggleClass('flipped');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flipper">
    <div class="row game-cards">
        <div class="container col-lg-6">
            <canvas id="game-circles"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 game-info">
            <h6 class="text-center">{{AwayTeam}} @ {{HomeTeam}}</h6>
            <p class="text-center">{{MatchTime}}</p>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <label for="home-team">{{HomeTeam}} -2.5</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Home Team Bet">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <label for="away-team">{{AwayTeam}}</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Away Team Bet">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block play-with-friends">Play With Friends</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try:  `$(this).toggleClass('flipped');` ?

Comment: Using the JQuery selector with 2 arguments apparently restricts scope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672034/multiple-parameters-for-jquery-selector
In your example, you are looking for items with class `flipper` that are descendants of `this`.

Comment: @Chaska I'm needing the toggleClass to apply to the flipper class not to the button.

Comment: @Ian interesting, any ideas of what I should do?

Comment: Where's the HTML?

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser I added it above.

Answer (score 0):

So please change your code to select `.flipper`:

```
    $('.play-with-friends').on('click', function(){
        $('.flipper').toggleClass('flipped');
    });
```

Comment: That isn't what I'm trying to achieve, it needs to be 'this'. Because what I have is dynamically generated.

Comment: @Bkes Really confused. Do you want to toggle the classname of `.flipper` by clicking the `.play-with-friends`?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$('.some-class', elem)` you're saying you want to target `.some-class` that's a child of `elem`. That's not what your HTML is showing – you actually have `.flipper` way above at the top level. How about using a different method, like [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), which will find an ancestor with the selector you specify:

```
$('.play-with-friends').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.flipper').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```